# getting 404 github error when trying to make public page

Tags: github

I keep getting this error. I followed the instructions exactly.

> 404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here. If you're trying to publish
>   one, read the full documentation to learn how to set up GitHub Pages
>   for your repository, organization, or user account.

I am trying to upload a simple `index.html` page and keep getting this error

for reference here is the page  https://github.com/xrpgiftsgive/xrpgiftsgive.github.io

I downloaded the desktop client.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, try and push an `index.md` file, as seen in "[Creating your site](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site)"

> In the root of the publishing source, create a new file called index.md that contains the content you want to display on the main page of your site.

Check the settings associating to your repository, to verify its [publication source](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) (which should be master for a *user* GitHub pages site)